# Autohotkey sequence numbers with a_index

Tags: autohotkey

I need a script to Send numbers between 1-5 hits Enter, then hits backspace and proceeds with the next number.

For example: Send 1, hit Enter, hit backspace, send 2, hit Enter, hit backspace, send3, ...

The problem is it sends all the numbers so 1 2 3 4 5 and then hits enter and backspace at the end, how can I fix this?

AHK script I got so far:

```
F1::
Loop, 5
{
    Send %A_Index%
    Send {Enter}{backspace}
}
Return
```

Comment: The script does exactly what you ask, and it does press enter and backspace every time. If you press backspace after pressing enter you get back to the previous line and it appears as if nothing happened.

Comment: That question bad understanding, why need backspace? `{BS}` or `{vk08}` or `{sc00E}` are depend on our keyboard systems